# Windows can't see or connect to Macs on a TF2 server

Tags: team-fortress-2, macos, windows

Trying to play Team Fortress 2 at work and the Windows machines can't connect to the Mac machine's server and vice versa, when we create a local server.

Tried connecting through the console directly to IP.

Tried setting sv_lan to 1.

Server won't repond. Says "connection failed after 4 retries."

Comment: Did you make sure that the firewalls on both were set to allow incoming connections?

Answer (score 1):

This shouldn't happen. But there are tutorials online to make a legit local server. But instead you could make a online server with a password. Then it would be a private server for your friends.